# Find string in string

Tags: c, pointers

I trying to write function that searching string in some string.
exmaple:
"qwerty" => key to search
"qasazqertyqwerty"
the program return 1 because qwerty found in the string.

my code function is:

```
int normal(char *str, char *str2)
{
    int temp=0;
    while(*str)
    {
        while(*str2)
        {
            if(*str == *str2)
            {
                temp+=1;
            }
            else if(temp == strlen(str2))
            {
                printf("%d", temp/strlen(str2));
            }
            str2++;
            str++;
        }
    }
return 0;
}
```

What the hell the problem in the program(logically)?

Comment: And I guess, it's not working... Is that why you ask the question?

Comment: Is it homework?  If not, use strstr instead.  http://linux.die.net/man/3/strstr

Comment: Is didnt homework.
is desnt has errors but it work

Comment: Sorry, didn't get your question.....?

Comment: if it's not homework, then use `strstr`.

Comment: Why was this closed? It is pretty obvious what's asked. I suppose you may have problems understanding it if you don't know the C language, but then this is a programming site...  Just because there are 10 PC programmers yelling strstr() doesn't mean that the question is invalid.

Answer (score 2):

The correct answer is obviously to use `strtstr`. But if you're still wondering why your code doesn't work, it is because your calling `strlen` on `str2` which you are incrementing. You should compute it first at the beginning of the function and then compare `temp` with it when you're done comparing chararcters.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should use strstr(). But to explain why your function does not work:

- Your function always returns 0, simply because there's only one return statement that is always reached.
- You will segfault if str is smaller then str2 because you forward both pointers in the inner loop.
- The condition temp == strlen(str2) will never be reached, because temp increments and the length of str2 decrements

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version of strstr() I wrote at some point, it should be MISRA-C compatible, save for the final cast, which is there for compatibility with the C standard's definition of strstr(). The `_` prefix was used to indicate that these are not library functions from string.h.

```
uint8* _strstr (const uint8* s1, const uint8* s2)
{
  uint16 length;
  const uint8* return_val;

  length = _strlen(s2);

  if(length == 0)
  {
    return_val = s1;
  }
  else
  {
    sint16 n;

    n = (sint16) _strlen(s1) + (sint16) 1 - (sint16) length;

    return_val = NULL;

    if(n >= 1)
    {
      while(n != 0)
      {
        n--;

        if(*s1 == *s2)
        {
          if(_memcmp(s1, s2, length) == 0)
          {
            return_val = (uint8*) s1;
          }
        }

        s1++;
      }
    }
  }

  return (uint8*)return_val;  
}
```